# D3: How to create a circular flow / Sankey diagram with 2 arcs

Tags: d3.js

I want to create a plot that visualizes the flow between the major that a person graduated in and the profession/sector they are working in after 1.5 years after graduating. I thought about using a Sankey diagram for this like the image below

[image: Sankey 2 flow example]

But wanted to make this slightly more visually interesting by making the left side (the majors studied) and the right side (the jobs) into two arcs. So it mights start to look as a Chord diagram, but with the two arcs pulled apart a bit . The example below sort of shows the idea of the two arcs (although not the correct flows between them)

[image: Example of two arcs]

The Hierarchical Edge bundling example of citations also looks somewhat similar to what I want to achieve, but here the lines have no thickness to show the number of people that flow from one end to the other and no 2 separate arcs (although I could create two white sections with no flows to imitate a separation)

[image: Hierarchical Edge Bundling example]

Does anybody have any examples on how to create a circular / arc like Sankey diagram? Or should I try this from a Chord diagram perspective?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It sounds like you would need a custom layout for this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured out how to do it myself, but it requires a bit of code changes. So I wrote an extensive tutorial on how to do it. You can find it [here](http://www.visualcinnamon.com/2015/08/stretched-chord.html)
[image: The resulting Stretched Chord]